# In spring boot, failing to insert data after checking whether that data pair exists in table, insertion will happen if that pair does not exist

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I've a table user_followers.It has two field user_id and following_id from user table. I'm supposed to insert user_id, following_id in this table after a check, if that pair already exists and status is inactive, then I'll just change the status which is working in my code. But if that pair does not exist, then insertion will happen.

table user_followers :

```
CREATE TABLE `user_followers` (
  `id` BIGINT(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` BIGINT(100) NOT NULL,
  `following_id` BIGINT(100) NOT NULL,
  `status` ENUM('active','inactive') NOT NULL,
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add/follower", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public JsonNode addFollower(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, @RequestBody String body) throws IOException {

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        utility.printCallingUrl(httpServletRequest);

        JSONObject request = new JSONObject(body);
        JSONObject response = new JSONObject();

        String auth = httpServletRequest.getHeader("Authorization");
        String authentication = utility.getBasicAuth();

        if (auth.equals(authentication)) {
            try {
                UserFollowers userFollower = new UserFollowers();

                User user = userService.getUser(request.getLong("userId"));

                User following = userService.getUser(request.getLong("followingId"));

                userFollower = userFollowersService.getUserFollowerYYYY(user, following);

                if (userFollower == null) {
                    userFollower.setFollower(user);
                    userFollower.setFollowing(following);
                    userFollower.setStatus("active");
                    userFollower = userFollowersService.createUserFollowers(userFollower);

                    response = new JSONObject(utility.convertPOJOtoStringHiding(userFollower));

                } else if (userFollower != null && userFollower.getStatus().equals("inactive")) {
                    userFollower.setStatus("active");
                    userFollower = userFollowersService.updateUserFollower(userFollower);
                    response = new JSONObject(utility.convertPOJOtoStringHiding(userFollower));

                } else {
                    response = new JSONObject();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                response = utility.createResponse(500, KeyWord.ERROR, e.toString());
                utility.showMessage(e.toString());
            }
        } else {
            response = utility.createResponse(500, KeyWord.ERROR, KeyWord.AUTHENTICATION);
        }

        return objectMapper.readTree(response.toString());
    }
```

service portion

```
public UserFollowers createUserFollowers(UserFollowers userFollowers) {
        return userFollowersRepository.save(userFollowers);
    }
```

repository portion

```
public UserFollowers getUserFollowerYYYY(User user, User following) {
        return userFollowersRepository.findByFollowerAndFollowing(user, following);
    }
```

That else if portion in controller is working fine, tested with data. not sure why

```
if (userFollower == null) {
                    userFollower.setFollower(user);
                    userFollower.setFollowing(following);
                    userFollower.setStatus("active");
                    userFollower = userFollowersService.createUserFollowers(userFollower);

                    response = new JSONObject(utility.convertPOJOtoStringHiding(userFollower));

                }
```

this portion is not working.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Do you get an Exception and if yes please post the StackTrace

Comment: This is the error I'm getting ```{
    "code": 500,
    "data": "java.lang.NullPointerException",
    "message": "ERROR"
}```

Comment: Please post the StackTrace from the log file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the `userFollower` object. In `if` condition you are checking whether it is null or not, and if it is null then you are setting values into it. But you cannot set values in null object. Below snippet must work for you:

```
if (userFollower == null) {
                userFollower = new UserFollowers();
                userFollower.setFollower(user);
                userFollower.setFollowing(following);
                userFollower.setStatus("active");
                userFollower = userFollowersService.createUserFollowers(userFollower);

                response = new JSONObject(utility.convertPOJOtoStringHiding(userFollower));

            }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for saving my day, thanks a bunch, been stuck here for quite long.

Comment: Silly mistakes usually take more time.:)